# trouble with pip and easy_install to install python packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am going to install `numpy` library as a `*.whl` file, as `numpy-1.9.2rc1+mkl- cp27-none-win32`, on my Windows 7 machine...

Here is my approaches to do that, are which `pip` and `easy_install` packages...
The odd thing is that both don't work in the case of either `Python 3.4` or `Python 2.7`...

Here are the trace of the attempts in the command prompt:

pip:

```
"C:\Users\Matinking\Desktop\numpy-  1.9.2rc1+
mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl"    f
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in r
InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 172, in from_line
return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 70, in __init__
req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2667
in parse
reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605
in parse_requirements
line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2573
in scan_list
raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', '   C:\\Users\\Matinking\\Desktop\\numer
performance.pdf', 'at', ':\\Users\\Matinking\\Desktop\\numericperformance.pdf'

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Matinking\pip\pip.log
```

and easy_install:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>easy_install.exe "C:\Users\Matinking\Desktop\numpy-  1.9.2rc1+
mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl"
Processing numpy-1.9.2rc1+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
Writing C:\Users\MATINK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-   jr2ijafr\numpy\setup.c
fg
Running numpy\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir    C:\Users\MATINK~1\AppData\Local\T
emp\easy_install-jr2ijafr\numpy\egg-dist-tmp-umy5kseg
This is the wrong setup.py file to run
No eggs found in C:\Users\MATINK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-jr2ijafr\nump
y\egg-dist-tmp-umy5kseg (setup script problem?)
```

Any idea for the problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade your pip to version 6.0, the .whl file you're using isn't compatible with earlier versions.

To bump up your pip version on Windows :
    python -m pip install -U pip

Answer (score 0):

**pip error** -> why were you running an install on a pdf?  That was never going to work.

**easy_install error** -> looks like you downloaded a python 2.7 binary and tried to install into a python 3.4 installation.

For scientific stack python, you are hard pressed to beat an [Anaconda python distribution](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: pip error -> I did copied the wrong trace... it has been edited now.
easy_install error -> none of 2.7 and 3.4 do work for the installation .